# Cant Use Created Function Outside of Ajax done() Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an jQuery Ajax() request like this

```
  function loadMarkers() {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var projects = data[i];
          var project = new esri.geometry.Point(projects.Longitude, projects.Latitude);
      }
  }

  var req1 = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "assets/app/data.php",
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      dataType: "JSON"
  });

  req1.done(function (data) {
      loadMarkers();
  });
```

The reason that I am trying to put the function `loadMarkers()` out id the `req1..done()` is I need to run 20 request and I don't want to repeat the `loadMarkers()` block inside all of the request `.done()` . Instead just call the `loadMarkers()` inside them but I am getting this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined

can you please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: you're not passing `data` to `loadMarkers` function?

Comment: i think you should pass data as a parameter to your loadMarkers() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope is determined by where a function is *defined* not from where it is called.

The `data` variable exists in a narrower scope to the `loadMarkers` function.

For you to access its value, you need to pass it as an argument.

(`loadMarkers(data);` and `function loadMarkers(data) {`)

NB: http://jshint.com/ would have highlighted this problem.

---

As a horrible hack, you could also define another `data` variable in a wider scope:

```
req1.done(function (data) {
  window.data = data;
  loadMarkers();
});
```

… but don't do that. Globals are a maintenance nightmare.